# Beamer: How To Include Logo In Every Slide?

Tags: beamer

I'm preparing a presentation using `beamer`.

As a prerequisite I need to include the logo of my funding scheme in each slide, preferably in the bottom left corner. The logo is just a .png image.

I know how to include graphics in my presentations, but is there an easy way to include an image in every slide in the bottom left corner (or somewhere else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that this is the best solution:

```
% Method to add an item that will appear in every slide
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \setlength\unitlength{1ex}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0) 
    % \put{} defines the position of the frame
    \put(140,6){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{
    \includegraphics{figures/image1.png}
    \includegraphics{figures/image2.png}
    \includegraphics{figures/image3.png}
    }}%
  \end{picture}%
}{}
```

Comment: How can I place it on the top-right corner?

Comment: @Echeban See my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Bottom right is easy:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\logo{\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

And with a dirty hack, it can be moved to the left:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\logo{\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{example-image}\hspace*{.88\paperwidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Surely many people come here wanting to add the logo at the **top-right** corner. For that, use this:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\hfill\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}\hspace{0.2cm}\vspace{-1cm}}
```

Adjust the parameters (`width`, `hspace`, `vspace`) accordingly.

Comment: This answer also changes the position of the slide title.