# How to put logo on the top-left corner using Boadilla theme?

Tags: beamer

I found an answer for my question for other types of themes, however not for Boadilla.

I managed to put logo on the top-right corner with this answer:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/561229/262804

But how can I put it on the top-left corner for every slide?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It works to put it on the right side. How to put it on the LEFT side?

Comment: Ah, sorry! I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the logo on the left side, remove the `\hfill` from the answer you linked to.

As this position will collide with the frametitle, I moved the frametitle to other side:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}\hspace{0.2cm}\vspace{-1cm}}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]